# Cannot call viewForAnnotation function in MapKit

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, mapkit

I have already checked many questions in StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

I am developing an iPad application. I created all interfaces in Storyboard.

For my project I created one view controller and corresponding .h .m files and linked them. Then I added MKMapView inside of the view controller then I referenced mapView in view controller file by using Interface Builder. I created bunch of points and showed them on map.

Everything was perfect until I decided to change pin colors. I followed MapCallout example from Apple Developer site. Then I Created custom annotation point class as you see below

CustomMKAnnotation.h file

```
@interface CustomMKAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{}
```

CustomMKAnnotation.m file

```
@implementation CustomMKAnnotation

- (NSString *)title {return @"title";}
- (NSString *)subtitle{return @"subtitle";}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = some latitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = some longitude;
    return theCoordinate; 
}
@end
```

Here my viewcontroller class

MapHolderViewController.h file

```
@interface MapHolderViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *mapAnnotations;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray *mapAnnotations;

-(void) addLatLong;

@end
```

MapHolderViewController.m file

```
@implementation MapHolderViewController

@synthesize myMap;
@synthesize mapAnnotations;

-(void) addLatLong{
    // I am adding annotations here
}
- (MKAnnotationView *)myMap:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // This function has never been called.
}
@end
```

I referenced delegate outlet from MKMapView to ViewController. I also set myMap.delegate=self; in MapHolderViewController.m file but it didn't work either.

Any insight is welcome.

Comment: You have an extraneous semicolon in - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;{

Comment: Thank you for correction but it didn't affect anything. I can show the pins on map but viewForAnnotation method has never been called.

Comment: We need more code to be able to help you: what you wrote should work, so the issue is in another part of the code…

Comment: I looked at different people's code, they usually right click on mapview and connect delegate to file owner. But I don't have that file owner option in Storyboard. What else code do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your delegate method is not named correctly.

You have written the delegate method like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)myMap:(MKMapView *)mapView 
    viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

So your method is `myMap:viewForAnnotation:`.

The correct header is:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
    viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

The method name *must* be `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`.

You can change the *parameter* names (the names after the parameter types) but not the parts in front of the parameter types which are part of the method name.

For example, this would be OK:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)myMap 
    viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

Comment: You can't imagine how happy I am now :) Thank you very much. It worked perfectly.