# (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: not firing on first view

Tags: iphone, ios

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView: is not firing on the first run of the view.

I load pins in from a JSON call.  The pins load fine with all the information but the call out(*see code) and turning them purple.(done in the -(MKAnnotationView *) mapView2:) however when I leave that tab and go back to it then it gets called and all is well.

Why this in not OK? Because end-users will not know that the map pins have a call out with phone call capabilities if they only check once.

**Progress Flow:** it loads the map. Loads the Pins. Changes the pins to purple with the call out. Then Zooms to pins and current location.  But on the first run it does not Change the pins with call out.

I have narrowed it down to -(MKAnnotationView *) mapView: not firing the first time on several tests however on one test it did fire but only was called on the second of two pins till the view was reloaded.

I am open to any suggestions to improve any of the code weather it pertains to this or not.  I always love learning better ways to do what I have done. So feel free with your criticisms.

**.h file**

> @class Reachability;

```
@interface LocationsViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
NSString *phone;

IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

CLLocationManager *locationManager;

NSURLConnection *theConnection;

Reachability* internetReachable;
Reachability* hostReachable;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *phone;

- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork;
- (void) mapPinsJSON;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation LocationsViewController

@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize phone;

MapAnnotation *ann1;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Locations", @"Locations");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locations"];
    }
    return self;
 }

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

//Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude= newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta=0.2;
    region.span.latitudeDelta =0.2;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [self zoomMapViewToFitAnnotations:self.mapView animated:YES];   
}

-(void)countDown{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    if([self connectedToNetwork] != YES)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OH NO!" message:@"To get the latest information you need a data or wi-fi connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(mapPinsJSON) withObject:nil];
    }
}

- (void) mapPinsJSON{

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/api/newlocations25/json.json"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for(id key in json) {
        id value = [json objectForKey:key];
        NSString *titlePin = [value valueForKey:@"address"];
        NSString *address = [value valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *latitude = [value valueForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSString *longitude = [value valueForKey:@"longitude"];

        NSArray* foo = [address componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
        NSString* address2 = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
        phone = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];

        double myLatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
        double myLongitude = [longitude doubleValue];

        MKCoordinateRegion location1;
        location1.center.latitude =myLatitude;
        location1.center.longitude= myLongitude;
        location1.span.longitudeDelta=0.1;
        location1.span.latitudeDelta =0.1;

        ann1 =[[[MapAnnotation alloc] init] autorelease];
        ann1.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",titlePin];
        ann1.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",address2];
        ann1.phone=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phone];
        ann1.coordinate= location1.center;
        [mapView addAnnotation:ann1];
        [phone retain];     
    }
}

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView2 viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if (annotation == mapView2.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }else{
        MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
        MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

        UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        [advertButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapphone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;

        MyPin.draggable = NO;
        MyPin.highlighted = YES;
        MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
        MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

        return MyPin;
    }
}

-(void)button:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)button.superview.superview;

    MapAnnotation *mapAnnotation = annotationView.annotation;

   UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",mapAnnotation.phone]]];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *Notpermitted=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:mapAnnotation.phone message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [Notpermitted show];
        [Notpermitted release];
    }   
}

- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork
{
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    BOOL internet;
    if ((internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi) && (internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN)) {
    internet = NO;
    } else {
    internet = YES;
    }
    return internet;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
}

#define MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC 0.014 //approximately 1 miles (1 degree of arc ~= 69 miles)

#define ANNOTATION_REGION_PAD_FACTOR 1.15

#define MAX_DEGREES_ARC 360

- (void)zoomMapViewToFitAnnotations:(MKMapView *)mapView3 animated:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSArray *annotations = mapView.annotations;

    int count = [mapView.annotations count];

    if ( count == 0) { return; } //bail if no annotations

    //convert NSArray of id <MKAnnotation> into an MKCoordinateRegion that can be used to set the map size

    //can't use NSArray with MKMapPoint because MKMapPoint is not an id

    MKMapPoint points[count]; //C array of MKMapPoint struct

    for( int i=0; i<count; i++ ) //load points C array by converting coordinates to points  
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [(id <MKAnnotation>)[annotations objectAtIndex:i] coordinate];
        points[i] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);    
    }

    //create MKMapRect from array of MKMapPoint

    MKMapRect mapRect = [[MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:count] boundingMapRect];

    //convert MKCoordinateRegion from MKMapRect

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect);

    //add padding so pins aren't scrunched on the edges

    region.span.latitudeDelta  *= ANNOTATION_REGION_PAD_FACTOR;

    region.span.longitudeDelta *= ANNOTATION_REGION_PAD_FACTOR;

    //but padding can't be bigger than the world

    if( region.span.latitudeDelta > MAX_DEGREES_ARC ) { region.span.latitudeDelta  = MAX_DEGREES_ARC; }

    if( region.span.longitudeDelta > MAX_DEGREES_ARC ){ region.span.longitudeDelta = MAX_DEGREES_ARC; }

    //and don't zoom in stupid-close on small samples

    if( region.span.latitudeDelta  < MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC ) { region.span.latitudeDelta  = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC; }

    if( region.span.longitudeDelta < MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC ) { region.span.longitudeDelta = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC; }

    //and if there is a sample of 1 we want the max zoom-in instead of max zoom-out

    if( count == 1 )   
    {    
        region.span.latitudeDelta = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = MINIMUM_ZOOM_ARC;     
    }
    [mapView3 setRegion:region animated:animated];   
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure the incorrectly-named mapView2:viewForAnnotation: delegate method is actually getting called?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919301/cannot-call-viewforannotation-function-in-mapkit.  Separate issue is calling addAnnotation from background thread (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853101/mapview-crashes-in-ios-6).

Comment: Yea in my code it is named mapView not mapView2 I was trying to trouble shoot it. just didn't turn it back.  Yes it runs on the second view showing just not the first time running the view.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel sheepish.  Here is what fixed it for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView.delegate = self;
}
```